# Is it possible for Socket.IO Event Handling to be like AJAX call event handling declaration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets, socket.io-1.0

When we are having and **ajax** call in *jquery* we can write it this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/url',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",          
    data: {name : "data"},
    beforeSend : function(){
    ...
    },
    success:function(data)
    {
    ...
    },  
    error : function(){
    ...
    }
}
});
```

Is this declaration template/style can also be applied to socket event handling in **Socket.IO**?

Can we do something like:

```
var socket = io.connect( );

socket.on({
    'connect' : function(){
     ...
     },
    'error' : function(){
    ...
    },
    'my custom event' : function(){
    ...
    }
}
```

)

Thanks!

Comment: You would have to either try it or look at the socket.io code to see if it supports an object instead of an event string.  I can't find any doc that indicates one way or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That gave me asn idea.

Answer (score 0):

In socket.io docs they show you can do it using the chain of calls:

```
socket.on(...)
      .on(...)
      .on(...)
```

If you really don't want it, you can simply write a module wrapping it:

```
yourNameSpace.Socket = (function(){
    var socket = null;

    this.config = function(){
        socket = io.connect("...");
    };

    this.on = function(events){
        for(var ev in events){
            if(typeof events == 'object' && events.hasOwnProperty(ev)){
                socket.on(ev, events[ev]);
            }
        }
    };

    this.getSocket = function(){
        return socket;
    };

    return this;
})();
```

Note that is not a constructor, but a module. It behavior is a singleton, so if you want more than one socket connection, simply convert it into a constructor. :)